# Can navigation property have [Required] atribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am studying asp.net mvc with Code First....

I have a class called Livro:

Here its the code

```
    public class Livro
    {

    [Key]
    public int LivroId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "E necessario titulo")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Titulo deve ter no maximo 100 caracteres")]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }


    public int AutorID { get; set; }

    public virtual Autor Autor { get; set; }
  }
```

As you can see  it has a Navigation property called `Autor` and FK called `AutorId`. But I have this code on the `Livro` controller (I didn't write this code, VS created based no my class).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Livro livro)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Livros.Add(livro);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.AutorID = new SelectList(db.Autores, "AutorId", "Nome", livro.AutorID);
        return View(livro);
    }
```

If i have `[Required]` on the `Autor` attribute, the `modelState.IsValid` becomes false because `livro.Autor` is *null*. So i must take it out.

But i was reading a book from Julia Lerman that its called "Programming EF Code-First" and
sometimes there is navigation properties with the `[Required]` attribute.

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because the View only refers to the `Livro` fields, not the `Autor` and the model binder is unable to create the `Autor` navigation property. You can create fields for the `Autor`, using smth like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Autor.AutorID);
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Autor.AutorName);
```

However, this will become painful and maybe you only need to select the author from the list. I would add the `Required` attribute to the `Livro.AutorID` property only and leave `Autor` as is.